# Change change background image by clicking a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an accordion style div with 3 boxes. When clicking it is opening and closing the content into view. I have an absolute positioned div with a background image behind that I need changed on each click. When I first load the page I am able to get it to work as you click each element. However, once you click any of those div boxes again it sticks to the same background image and won't cycle through. I have tried using .next(), .closest() but not working.

```
<?php 

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'services',
  's' => '-demand' // will exclude all post with the title name "Demand" present
);
 $services = new WP_Query($args);

 ;?>
 <?php if($services->have_posts()) : ?>
<section class="section__wrapper" id="services__set">
 <div class="services__accordion" id="class-accordions">
    <div class="services__container">
        <?php $i = 1; 
        while($services->have_posts()): $services->the_post();
        global $post;
        $post_slug = $post->post_name; ?>

            <div class="services__col" id="<?php echo $post_slug;?>">
                <span class="h2 services__title"><?php the_title();?></span>
                <div class="services__content">
                    <?php $barreDesc = get_field('class_description'); if($barreDesc): ?><p><?php echo $barreDesc; ?></p><?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="services__btn">
                        <a class="btn white-btn" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/locations/">Find A Studio</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="services_bg" style="background-image:url(<?php the_field('service_feature_image');?>);"></div>
        <?php $i++; endwhile;wp_reset_postdata();?>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.services__content').css('height', '0');
$('.services__col').first().addClass("active-reveal");
$('.services_bg').first().addClass("active");
$('.services__col').click(
    function() { //When you click on a button...
        var isActive = $(this).hasClass('active-reveal'); 
        if( isActive ){  //If it already has an active class...
            $(this).removeClass('active-reveal'); //...it loses the active class....
        }
        else{ //If it does NOT already have an active class...
            $('.services__col').removeClass('active-reveal'); //all buttons lose the active class...
            $(this).addClass('active-reveal'); //...except this one.
        }
        if ($('.services__col').attr("class") == "active-reveal") {
          $(this).next('.services_bg').removeClass('active');
        } else {
          $(this).next('.services_bg').addClass('active');
        }
    });
 });

</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: I was able to solve this issue by adding the following: 
                $('.services_bg').removeClass('active'); inside my last else statement. Update

Answer (score 0):

Updated code with answer

```
<?php 

$args = array(
      'post_type' => 'services',
      's' => '-demand' // will exclude all post with the title name "Demand" present
   );
   $services = new WP_Query($args);

;?>
<?php if($services->have_posts()) : ?>
<section id="services__set">
    <div class="services__accordion" id="class-accordions">
        <div class="services__container">
            <?php $i = 1; 
            while($services->have_posts()): $services->the_post();
            global $post;
            $post_slug = $post->post_name; ?>

                <div class="services__col" id="<?php echo $post_slug;?>">
                    <span class="h2 services__title"><?php the_title();?></span>
                    <div class="services__content">
                        <?php $barreDesc = get_field('class_description'); if($barreDesc): ?><p><?php echo $barreDesc; ?></p><?php endif; ?>
                        <div class="services__btn">
                            <a class="btn white-btn" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/locations/">Find A Studio</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="services_bg" style="background-image:url(<?php the_field('service_feature_image');?>);"></div>
            <?php $i++; endwhile;wp_reset_postdata();?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.services__content').css('height', '0');
    $('.services__col').first().addClass("active-reveal");
    $('.services_bg').first().addClass("active");
    $('.services__col').click(
        function() { //When you click on a button...
            var isActive = $(this).hasClass('active-reveal'); 
            if( isActive ){  //If it already has an active class...
                $(this).removeClass('active-reveal'); //...it loses the active class....
            }
            else{ //If it does NOT already have an active class...
                $('.services__col').removeClass('active-reveal'); //all buttons lose the active class...
                $(this).addClass('active-reveal'); //...except this one.
            }
            if ($('.services__col').attr("class") == "active-reveal") {
              $(this).next('.services_bg').removeClass('active');
            } else {
                $('.services_bg').removeClass('active');
              $(this).next('.services_bg').addClass('active');
            }
        });
});

</script>
<?php endif;?>
```